# How to let SonarQube be aware of test classes using different naming conventions

Tags: sonarqube, cloudbees

I have changed the naming convention of some tests to end in **IT.java or **IntegrationTest.java

What sonar properties need to be modified so that Sonar can detect the naming convention of the tests as integration test classes ?

Comment: What is the difference between this post and your previous post? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: Two different topics. One deals with class naming conventions for test detection & the other deals with directory paths.

Comment: It means that you mix source code and test files? Otherwise defining a list of directory should be sufficient.

Comment: Nothing is being mixed. Unit tests and Integration tests are in different directories for specific reasons.  Based on the following link [SONAR Unit & integration Tests](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Unit+Tests,+Integration+Tests+and+Code+Coverage), do I need to change a property similar to: sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Tests;*.UnitTests in order to tell SONAR that the test classes have a different naming convention ? If so, what would be that property name ?